# Python Selenium send text to hidden input element using javascript

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to make code that will automatically write variables to input elements. The email field is hidden. How can I put it there?
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import random 
url = "url"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
Firstname = "Name"
Lastname = "Name"
First_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("First")
First_textbox.send_keys(Firstname)
Last_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("Last")
Last_textbox.send_keys(Lastname)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('email').#What argument should I use there?
```

Picture what it looks like:[image]

If it is not possible to put the email as a variable, I can put it as a string

Comment: The getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value.

Comment: How is this javascript related?

Comment: @12944qwerty As far as I know, after driver.execute_script you have to use the  javascript command

Comment: @vitaliis So how can I put there email?

Comment: First try clicking on that element and after that sendkeys

Comment: @Prophet Clicking on that works, but when I type send_keys I get an error: Message: javascript error: document.getElementById(...).send_keys is not a function

Comment: sendkeys also doesn't work

Comment: Why are you using that strange command instead of email.send_keys("Your text") where email is an element, similarly to First_textbox  and Last_textbox?

Comment: Because with it is_displayed() returns false

Comment: 1) So what? 2) Even after the click?

Comment: 1) I am getting an error: Exception has occurred: ElementNotInteractableException
Message: element not interactable 2) Yes

Comment: Add html code of these elements

Comment: First name: <input class="sign-share-community-form-input" maxlength="45" name="First" placeholder="Imię" required="required" type="text">                                             Email: <input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="sign-share-community-form-input" name="Email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%\x26'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+$" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" type="email">